# Rspec test for model create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

This is my first time writing a test case. I have model where I am doing a callback to create an object for another model.

```
class Model1
 after_save :create_model2_object

 def create_model2_object
  Model2.create(id: self.id, name: self.name) 
 end
end
```

The test case I wrote is as follows:

**model1_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe Model1, type: :model do
  context 'validation tests' do
     it 'ensures article attrs presence' do
        page = Model2.create(entity: self.id, name: self.name)
        expect(page).to eq(true)
     end
  end
end
```

When I run this both the development and test data goes empty. I know I am doing something completely wrong. Could somebody please help me here?

Comment: You `context 'validation tests' do` is wrong. You are not testing validations here.

Comment: `it 'ensures article attrs presence' do` - What are you actually trying to test?

Comment: Why would `expect(page).to eq(true)` ever be `true`? As far as i remember, `create` returned the created object on success.

Comment: I am trying to test if the created object of Model2 has the attrs of current object of Model1.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I am just trying everything that I find.

Comment: I think this is a classic case where you´re abstracting out the example far too much. Instead try to use the actual problem you are solving.

Comment: Earlier I actually posted the actual problem with very little abstraction but I didnt seem to get any response. So I thought I make it as simple as possible for people to answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe Model1, type: :model do
  context 'validation tests' do
     it 'ensures article attrs presence' do 
         expect{Model1.create(entity: "entity_id", name: 'name')}.to change{Model2.count}.by(1)
     end
  end
end
```

Comment: What is `page = ` part?

Comment: What is `self.id` and `self.name` here?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh `self.anything` gives the attribute value of the current object. So I am storing the `id` and `name` of the curent object here.

Comment: What about database cleaner part.? For some reason every time I run a test case the db is going empty. Do you know the reason for that?

Comment: @user3576036 yes, `self.something` gives the value of that attribute/method but where do you set `self` here? What object does it refer to? Or am i wrong in assuming that you need to create one using fixtures/factorybot etc. and use it as `subject` in your tests?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh sorry I was wrong, Now I change the answer.